# How can I get vertical alignment in flow slot in Shoes?

Tags: shoes, vertical-alignment

The default vertical alignment in a `flow` slot is apparently to top-align the elements.  Here's a sample:

```
Shoes.app (:title => "Vertical Alignment", :width => 300, :height => 150) do
  background "#DFA"
  flow :margin => 30 do
    title "BIG"
    tagline "MEDIUM"
    inscription "SMALL"
  end
end
```

How do I get the `flow` slot to center-align its elements short of calculating a `:rise` value for each element?  I would have expected a vertical-alignment style for `flow` slots and a horizontal-alignment style for `stack` slots, but I don't see anything like that.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no style for vertical alignment.  There is horizontal alignment which is useful in stacks:

```
Shoes.app (:title => "Horizontal Alignment", :width => 300, :height => 150) do
  background "#DFA"
  stack :margin => 30 do
    title "BIG", :align => 'center'
    tagline "MEDIUM", :align => 'center'
    inscription "SMALL", :align => 'center'
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that Shoes is very much still a work in progress, so _why will probably get around to it eventually.

Comment: Thanks, @Pesto.  Let's hope _why reads this, and I'll try to be more patient.